# Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

So this is Error Message :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

> Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

> Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993]
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.test1</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
                        </dependency>
            
                 <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                 </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>`

@Entity
@Table(name= "ordertransactions")
public class OrderTransaction {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="order_name",nullable = false)
    private String OrderName;
    
    @OneToMany
     @JoinColumn(name = "Customer_Id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = true,nullable = false)
     private Customer customer;
     
    
    public OrderTransaction(Long id, String OrderName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.OrderName = OrderName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOrderName() {
        return OrderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String OrderName) {
        this.OrderName = OrderName;
    }

    
}



public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository <Customer, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value ="SELECT ordertransactions.id, Customer.name" +
"FROM ordertransactions" +
"INNER JOIN Customer ON orderransactions.id = customer.id;" ,nativeQuery = true)
    int deleteCustomer(Customer Customer); 
    
@Query(value="SELECT name, city FROM Customer")
    Customer findCustomerByName(@Param("nameCustomer") String name);

}
```

so i want to join CustomerId in table ordertransaction, i had solved by myself but i dont found the solution.. please help me.

Comment: please add a bit more information as to what caused this error, what other code you have been running and what you have tried to resolve it.

Comment: more information is needed @apin

Comment: These errors come from using incompatible library versions. You are trying to outsmart Spring Boot (and its dependency management) by including Hibernate jars yourself.

Comment: Could you show pom.xml

Comment: @GauravDhiman i already add pom